# Finding the geometric shape

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

> Draw the geomatrix region of $|z^2-1|=1$

$$|z^2-1|=1$$

$$|(x+iy)^2-1|=1$$
$$|x^2-y^2-1+ixy|=1$$
$$\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(xy)^2}=1$$
$$\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(xy)^2}=1$$

Let $a=x^2, b=y^2$

$$\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2-2a+2b+1}=1$$
$$a^2+b^2-ab-2(a+b)=0$$

How should I continue?

Comment: its probably an oval or smt

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2-y%5E2-1)%5E2%2B(xy)%5E2%3D1

Comment: First off, the imaginary part of $z^2$ is $2xy$ not $xy$. For a peek at the answer see http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/lemniscate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us write $ z = r e^{i\varphi} $, then the equation says : 
$$1=|z^2-1|^2=(z^2-1)\overline{ (z^2-1) } = \left(r^2e^{2i\varphi}-1\right)\cdot\left(r^2e^{-2i\varphi}-1\right)$$

Expanding the expression above rise in equation (using the Euler's formula in the form $e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$) :

$$1=1+r^4-2r^2 \cos(2\varphi)$$

Clearly if $r=0$ the equation is solved immediatelly so $z=0$ is a lies on the region. If $r\neq0$ then

$$r=\pm \sqrt{2\cos2\varphi}$$

This is the equation of a ***lemniscate***.